# how select two radio button with one click?

Tags: html, css

```
<label for="foo">choose?</label>
<br>
<input id="id_1" type="radio" value="1" name="349">Google
<input id="id_2" type="radio" value="2" name="349">chrome
<br>
<input id="id_3" type="radio" value="3" name="349">Microsoft
<br>
<input id="id_4" type="radio" value="4" name="349">IE
<br>
```

When the key is pressed Google, Chrome button is selected at the same time.
Thank you!

Comment: You can't select two radio button, you want `checkbox`

Comment: What to do? How to do it?

Comment: Do you want that when Google radio is selected, automatically Chrome should be selected ?

Comment: @hamed The question is not clear, add the current behaviour and expected behaviour

Comment: yes ,That's exactly what I want!

Comment: 2 solutions : use different name of radio button. One for the browser second one for the compagnie. Or use checkbox with a lot of control

Comment: Why dont you use check box?

Comment: Why don't you just change `Google` to `Google Chrome` ?

Comment: I want that when Google radio is selected, automatically Chrome should be selected. I want not use checkbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want easy answer then go with jquery solution and don't forget to change the name of radio button or else it will be difficult with same name... See here [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/uhxytocn/)
I have added jquery `onclick event` and on click of google, selecting the another radio button. See fiddle for more info..hope it will help

Comment: check fiddle plz..i already mention that..i want my answer clean that's why i added jsfiddle..

Comment: @Leothelion You just mentioned in your [previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32220725/how-select-two-radio-button-with-one-click#comment52325022_32220948), that the other answer without code is low quality one, and you have committed the same mistake now.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, thanx for checking my history..but i have provided jsfiddle..please check that comment back as there were no code lines or jsfiddle but in my answer i have proivded jsfiddle with code and also mention that what i did in that fiddle..m wonder why can't you see difference between my answer and that answer.

Comment: well let me tell you one condition..i want to center align my div with display:table-cell, how can i..and if user will post make it center..then this is the answer?? or use vertical-align:middle please..this will be the answer..i don't know why you are pointing to my answer when its clear with jsfiddle..

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions :

you need to change only two radio buttons 
 - Google Chrome
 - Microsoft IE

and in this case you can make 2 radio buttons.

second solution, you can use jquery with same html.

if id_1 clicked then also id_2 should be checked and so on with 2nd Microsoft IE.

Comment: well its not the answer..but the comment..come with proper solution and please don't post such low quality answer without any code..

Answer (score 0):

Radio button is supposed to be allowing only a single selection. You have got a few solutions here:

1. Have a sub radio button.

   - Radio button with a different name.
2. Have checkboxes instead of radio buttons.

   - Checkboxes are really used for multiple selections.

**Snippet**

This would demonstrate all the solutions:

```html
<h2>Radios</h2>

<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="comp" name="comp"> Company: Google
    <ul>
      <li><input type="radio" name="comp-g" id=""> Chrome</li>
      <li><input type="radio" name="comp-g" id=""> Chrome</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="comp" name="comp"> Company: Microsoft</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="comp" name="comp"> Company: Apple</li>
</ul>

<h2>Checkboxes</h2>

<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="comp" name="comp"> Company: Google
    <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="comp-g" id=""> Chrome</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="comp-g" id=""> Chrome</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="comp" name="comp"> Company: Microsoft</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="comp" name="comp"> Company: Apple</li>
</ul>
```